# Read Txt file and fill into Vector3 in three.js

Tags: three.js

I have a .txt file which consists of x,y,z coordinates of a drone flight
example:

121.12     98.12     1.02

122.98     98.88     3.05

First column is x, second column is y, and third column is z.

I have tried with file loader and output the data to console, but now I don't know how to save x,y,z to Vector3

```
    var loader = new THREE.FileLoader();

//load a text file and output the result to the console
loader.load(
    // resource URL
    'example.txt',

    // onLoad callback
    function ( data ) {
        // output the text to the console
        console.log( data )
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `data.split( '\n' )` in order to split your string into an array of substrings. Next, you iterate over the array and split each line like so `line.split(" ")`. You can then parse the resulting values to floats and assign them to a new instance of `Vector3`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I get the coordinates loaded and tried to split them like this: 
const atoms =  data.split('\n').map(line => line.trim()).slice(1).map(line => line.split(' ').map(Number)).map(([x,y,z]) => ({x,y,z})); .. and when I output atoms in console, I get unavailable.